In what buffer the 'dmesg' messages are stored in linux?
I know the dmesg command prints the messaged stored in a ring buffer. But from the linux source code, what is the buffer's name? I want to look into the buffer after the linux is killed without any message. I suspect it's not by a software trap (hence no panic message) but I can examine the memory (with some System.map and virtual to physcial address conversion).

kernel/printk/printk.c (from a v4.18 Kernel just since that is the Kernel on the PC from which are typing this answer) has the following which defines the record buffer:
/* record buffer */
#define LOG_ALIGN __alignof__(struct printk_log)
#define __LOG_BUF_LEN (1 << CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT)
static char __log_buf[__LOG_BUF_LEN] __aligned(LOG_ALIGN);
static char *log_buf = __log_buf;
static u32 log_buf_len = __LOG_BUF_LEN;

From looking at printk.c:

__log_buf is an array with a size set during Kernel configuration to ensure there is a log buffer during early boot. The size of __log_buf is set from the CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT config parameter.

setup_log_buf is called boot and will allocate space for a new log buffer if either:

The number of possible CPUs is more than a certain value (based upon the CONFIG_LOG_CPU_MAX_BUF_SHIFT config parameter).
log_buf_len is used on the Kernel command line to specify a ring buffer size which is greater than __LOG_BUF_LEN.

When a new log buffer is allocated:

The existing log buffer contents from __log_buf is copied to the new allocated buffer.
log_buf is changed to point at the new ring buffer.
log_buf_len is changed to the size of the new ring buffer.


The ring buffer is accessed via the log_buf pointer and log_buf_len length.


Looking at /boot/System.map-`uname -r on a v4.18 Kernel can see the addresses of the log_buf and log_buf_len variables.
This answer should hopefully show how to start examining the memory containing the ring buffer. See printk.c for the internal format of the ring buffer, which uses struct printk_log. I haven't checked when the internal format of the ring buffer has changed between Kernel versions.

Yeah, it looks like it. I examined the location pointed to by log_buf using jtag and it contained ascii-looking string but couldn't decif it. I'll take some time to figure it out. Thank you.
